# Unable to connect to ip address when connected to Cisco VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I am a lifelong Windows user trying to move to Ubuntu. I am struggling to connect to my work vpn and load the address `10.192.30.249`.

Under the configuration for the Cisco VPN I have configured the route `10.192.0.0` with netmask `255.255.0.0`.

I can connect to the vpn without any problems and when I run `ifconfig`, this is the `vpn0` details:

```
vpn0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.19.253.82  P-t-P:10.19.253.82  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: 2a00:47c0:201:ffff::a/64 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1406  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:475 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:46938 (46.9 KB)
```

The outcome of `route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         dsldevice.lan   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
5-10-235-196-eu dsldevice.lan   255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp2s0
10.18.0.0       *               255.254.0.0     U     50     0        0 vpn0
10.19.252.0     *               255.255.252.0   U     50     0        0 vpn0
10.192.0.0      *               255.252.0.0     U     0      0        0 vpn0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

When I run:
`ip route get 10.192.30.249`

It shows:

> 10.192.30.249 dev vpn0  src 10.19.253.82 
>       cache

This makes me think that everything should be working fine. Unfortunately I am unable to load the ip address in the browser.

I'm totally stuck and not sure what the next steps to debug are. What look like the same routing settings work in Windows 10.

Comment: What is the output of `traceroute 10.192.30.249`? You might have to install traceroute with `sudo apt install traceroute` first, I had to anyway.

Comment: What happens when you open the address in your browser? Does it take forever until it fails? Does it fail quickly? What is the error message? Also, run `ping 10.192.30.249` and add the output to your question.

Comment: >"Unfortunately I am unable to load the ip address in the browser." // is there a web server on that address. Can you `nmap` it? I notice you use "10.192.X.X" and "10.19.2xx.X" - could that be a typo?? Note that `route` is showing you that address can be handled, it doesn't show it exists on the local network, nor that there is a server on it.

Comment: @psych - with command : <netstat tulpen> or with command : <ss -arl> you would see more ...